# Troublesome extra space in matrix with ConTeXt

Tags: spacing, context, matrices

I need to display a column vector in a table and, by doing it, an extra space occurs like an empty extra number. How can I fix this please ?

[image: extra space in matrix]

```
\starttable[|r|l|]
        \NC     $u=\startmatrix 1 \NR 2 \NR 3 \NR \stopmatrix$
           \NC \type {u=[1;2;3]}        \NC\AR
\stoptable
```

NB : the code `$u=\startmatrix 1 \NR 2 \NR 3 \NR \stopmatrix$` works fine in inline mode. I defined matrix the usual way like this.

```
\definemathmatrix[matrix]
             [left={\left(\,},
              right={\,\right)},
              align=middle]
```

I also tried to use `\startformula ... \stopformula.` in my table but the same extra space occurs...

All ideas are welcome. I use MkIV luatex version of ConTeXt (ubuntu depot version) Thanks.

Comment: What does `context --version` say? I thought that this was fixed a while ago.

Comment: I get the correct output with `ConTeXt 2014.10.08`. Unrelated to this, but the correct syntax for `\startmatrix` is `\startmatrix \NC ... \NR \NC ... \NR \stopmatrix`; you do not have `\NC` in each line.

Comment: `context --version` gives 
`mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.60
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf     /tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2013.05.28 00:36`

I had issues with standalone version to display Chinese... and everything worked with this repo version found in ubuntu so I got used to it, but it I didn't know it was a 1 year old version. Is there any solution with my 2013 version ? Else, I'll try to work with both versions...
Thanks for all questions/answers here !

Comment: The easier solution will be to use the standalone version. If there is something wrong with processing chinese with that version, report it on the mailing list and it should be fixed, Backporting bugfixes to older versions is more difficult.

Comment: I understand that. I'll try my best with the standalone version. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this bug has been fixed very long ago.